# Thread safe disposal of WCF service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, concurrency, tpl-dataflow

I' trying to implement a fault recovery mechanism which will dispose a WCF connection on error (and then periodically attempt to reconnect and retry)

Essentially the relevant code is just

```
try
{
    _client.DoSomthing();
}
catch
{
    _client.Dispose();
}
```

The problem is that the above code runs inside a TPL dataflow block and must be thread safe. I'm having problems with the client being disposed while in use by other threads. I *don't* really want to put a lock around the whole thing as I then lose concurrent uploads and performance suffers.

I'm looking for some way to block new threads using the client but not try to dispose until I know any current calls are completed. And then to ensure that only one thread performs the dispose.

I'm imaging some mechanism along the lines of below (pseudo) code

```
using (var counter = new ThreadCounter())
{
    try
    {
        if (!faulted)
            _client.DoSomthing();
    }
    catch
    {
        faulted = true;

        counter.BlockNewThreadsEntering() 

        if (counter == 1)
             _client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is there anything in the framework that would let me achieve this? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK it's not safe to use the same client concurrently in any way. I therefore suspect that this can never be made to work reliably.

Comment: @usr - huh?  Of course you can use the same client concurrently.  Yes, it certainly complicates matters somewhat, but async calls are now more or less normal, and if your server has it's concurrency mode set to multi-threaded then it can handle it just fine.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch the server does not know or care what client is being used. The client does not know or care what the server has set as a concurrency mode. This is all about whether the ClientBase class is thread-safe. The docs say it isn't.

Comment: @usr - it is incorrect that the server does not know which client is which as the server handles concurrency based on session (if session is being used).  It knows that two different sessions are two different clients and if your instance mode is Per Session and Concurrency is Multiple, it will allow multiple requests per client (ie per session).  By default, the server throttles multiple calls per instance, only allowing one call at a time.  But multiple instances can run concurrently, and if you've configured concurrency to Multiple then multiple client requests to the same instance happen.

Comment: @usr - I'm not sure which docs you mention about ClientBase, but thread-safe (or not) is not the same thing as being able to handle concurrent calls, since concurrent calls can happen on the same thread with async.

Comment: That's not the same thing. Concurrent (outstanding) requests do not mean concurrent execution on the same object. You might be allowed to call BeginXxx multiple times but not at the same time. Also, I don't see any note that it is legal to initiate multiple async IOs on the same ClientBase. This certainly cannot be assumed. All objects are not thread-safe by default.

Comment: @usr - Client base is perfectly thread safe to make calls simultaneously with multiple threads.  There's plenty of support out there to back this up, such as here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/12/18/concurrent-channel-performance.aspx "The channel interfaces are thread-safe so that multiple callers can use them at the same time without getting garbled messages".  On top of that ClientBase says it's thread safe when used as a static member, so that means there's nothing inherently thread-unsafe about it.  It does its own locking if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> Or any other suggestions?

Just follow the rule "one thread - one client". There's no reason to share database connections, http clients, service clients and so on between threads.

As a rule, all of these objects has a tiny state, and any efforts to minimize resource usage via sharing them is a headache, since you need to synchronize cross-thread access to prevent objects' state from corruption.

If your code considers system resources while creating new threads (thus, doesn't create 100 threads running on 4 CPU cores), one service client per thread isn't a problem.

Comment: it's not something that I really have control over unfortunately.

Comment: THen go to those that have and send them here. Many of us refuse to wok around hodge podge idiotic decisions because a bad practice is a bad practive regardless how much energy you waste trying to work around it.